# Oracle SQL and autonumbering: how to retrieve an OUT parameter - outside the procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, filemaker

On an earlier stage, our system was provided with tables that hold last used autonumber (instead of using sequences). We are now redoing the client solution for the system, and need to 'reinvent' how to fetch next record number - **by SQL**.

The client application is made in FileMaker, the database still resides in Oracle. The challenge is to update last used autonumber AND supply it to the new record initiated in the client - in one operation.

A **SELECT** statement can retrieve the last used number.
An **UPDATE** statement can increment the last used number.

A function selecting and returning the number is not allowed to contain update statements.

A procedure may do the update, and may retain the new value returning it into an OUT parameter, but does not return the new value to the client - unless the client in some way can read the OUT parameter from the procedure (I do not think it reads DBMS_OUTPUT).

If the procedure proceeds to do an INSERT on the table where the client is preparing an INSERT, the inserts will not be identical, as far as I can see.

So - *is there a syntax* that will make the OUT value accessible to the client as result of an SQL statement including a procedure call (perhaps making the OUT parameter in some way refer to the client's new record recnr field), or is this altogether a blind alley?

Comment: What about the [`RETURNING CLAUSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/returninginto_clause.htm) ? here is an example with an update http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#BABHDGIG

Comment: Does Filemaker not support explicit (multiple statement) transactions? Seems like that is all you need from a simple standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

regarding syntax - You need to wrap your  PL/SQL procedure with out param into function (you can use overloaded function with the same name in the same package) and return out value as function result.

Regarding design - I do not recommend to use "home-made" mechanism to replace sequences. Sequences are much better optimised and more reliable solution.